# Having trouble rendering an index page after handling an error check in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble rerendering an an index page when there in an error. If the two fields are blank it should render welcome/index

```
def index
    if params[:cityzip] == "" && params[:searchname] == ""
        p "***************"
        @error = "You must enter a location"
        p "***************"
        render'welcome/index.html.erb'
    elsif params[:searchname] != "" 
        @providers = Provider.searchname(params[:searchname].capitalize)
    elsif params[:cityzip] != "" && params[:insurance][0] == "---"
        @providers = Provider.search(params[:cityzip])
    elsif params[:cityzip] != "" && params[:insurance][0] != ""
        @providers = Provider.search(params[:cityzip]).insurancesearch(params[:insurance][0].upcase)            
    end
    @searchname = params[:searchname]
    @search = params[:cityzip]
    @insurancesearch = params[:insurance]
    @locations = []
    @filters = []
    if params[:searchname] != ""
        @filters << params[:searchname]
    end
    if params[:insurance][0] != ""
        @filters << params[:insurance][0]
    end
    def latlon(city)
        url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + city + '&key=AIzaSyC_VdOLBtVFbR-6rRP5-hRFXChHa78bDmM'
        citylatlon =[]
        city = open(url).read
        city = JSON.parse(city)

        city["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]
    end

    @providers = @providers.order("lastname")
    @providers = @providers.order('distance asc').paginate(:per_page => 30, :page => params[:page])
end
```

The index page is in the 'Welcome' folder in the "Views" folder.  The code is in the Providers controller.  I have a controller for Welcome also that has an index method.  This is the error I'm getting:

```
Started GET "/providers?utf8=%E2%9C%93&insurance%5B%5D=AETNA&cityzip=&searchname=" for ::1 at 2017-06-10 12:06:04 -0500
Processing by ProvidersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "insurance"=>["AETNA"], "cityzip"=>"", "searchname"=>""}
Geokit is using the domain: localhost

Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms (Views: 20.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

NoMethodError (undefined method 'order' for nil:NilClass):`

app/controllers/providers_controller.rb:36:in 'index'
  Rendering /Users/dragunfly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/dragunfly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/dragunfly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (5.7ms)
  Rendering /Users/dragunfly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/dragunfly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendering /Users/dragunfly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb`

  Rendered /Users/dragunfly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/dragunfly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (139.2ms)
```

`NoMethodError (undefined method 'order' for nil:NilClass):` this error happens when it goes further down the controller so anything after that should be irrelevant.

`layouts/application` is the layout for the page which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Referralgps</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  </head>

  <body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse nobottommargin ">
    <div class="container">
    <a href="/welcome/index" ><img src="/images/referral_gps_logo.png"></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
    <%= yield %>
    <footer class="visible-lg-*">
        <img src="/images/footlogo.png">

    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works fine when I first load the page.  But when I try to render it because of an error it doesn't work.

Comment: Update the question with full error stacktrace

Comment: "This is the error I'm getting..." - where's the error?

Comment: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms (Views: 20.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) It is not rendering the page instead it just goes down and tries to run the rest of the controller.

Comment: Update the question with `providers_controller` code

Answer (score 0):

In your first condition you do not define `@providers` variable. Therefore, it is `nil` and it does not understand method `order`.

At least you could check for `@providers` variable presence before sending `order` to that.

To make things more readable:

```
 def index
   if missing_location?
     @error
   else
     your_main_flow
   end
 end

 private

 def missing_location?
   params[:cityzip].empty? && params[:searchname].empty? 
 end
```

Also move `latlon(city)` from the scope of `index` method to a private scope of the entire controller.

Comment: But shouldn't it render the index page before it even gets to that?

Comment: No, `render` will not return you from a controller.

Comment: Okay I set @providers to a random value and it worked

Comment: @almusavi: you also could have used `return` after the `render`